# Prime factorization of

Tags: prime-factorization

For a positive integer $k$, let $S_k$ be the set of numbers $n > 1$  that are expressible as
$n = kx + 1$ for some positive integer $x$. The set $S_k $ is closed under multiplication.
That is: If $a, b$ ∈$ S_k $then $ab $∈ $S_k$.
Definition. Suppose $n ∈ S_k$ . If $n$ is expressible as $n = ab$ for some $a, b ∈ S_k$ , then $n$
is called $k$-composite. Otherwise $n$ is called a $k$-prime.
For example, $S_4 = \{5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, . . . \}$ . The numbers
$25, 45, 65, 81, . . . $ are $4$-composites, while $5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 29, . . . $ are $4$ -primes.

1. For which $n ∈ S_4$ are $4$-primes? (Answer in terms of the standard prime factorization of $n$.
   Show: Every $n∈ S_4 $is either a $4$-prime or a product of some $4$-primes.
   But “unique factorization into $4$-primes” fails. To prove that, find some
   $n = p_1p_2 · · · p_s $ and $n = q_1q_2 · · · q_t $ where each $p_j $and $q_k $ is a $4$-prime, but the list
   $(q_1, . . . , q_t)$ is not just a rearrangement of the list $(p_1, . . . , p_r)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  think about $441=3^2\cdot 7^2=4\cdot 110+1 \in S4$.  It is 4-composite, how does it factor?  Can you generalize?

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you so much. I got it right now.

Comment: The FAQ encourages you to write an answer to your question, which you can accept after some delay (two days?).  It will give us a full answer and show that you have really solved it.  I am glad my hint helped, but writing up a full answer may help your thinking as well.  I have found holes in my arguments in that process.

Comment: If for original Q=p1p2p3p4*...*pn+1, and there isn't any unique factorization in there. Could we suggest that the prime in 4k+1 is Q=4(p1p2p3p4*...*pn)+1. But if like that, how do we know that there is no unique factorization in that?

Comment: It is important that if you multiply two numbers that are equivalent to $3 \bmod 4$ you get a number that is equivalent to $1 \bmod 4$. Most numbers that have at least four factors of the shape $3 \bmod 4$ will fail to have unique factorization.  That is how I found this example.  To prove there is no unique factorization you just need to find one example that has two factorizations, and $441$ is one example because $441=9 \cdot 49=21^2$ and all the things on the right cannot be factored.